# How do I add line breaks after each tag in MSXML?

Tags: xml, whitespace, msxml

I've created a new element/tag with doc->createElement named file, and then appended that to my files tag as a child element. After adding a few file-tags, the output in the xml file looks like this:

```
<file/><file/><file/><file/><file/></files>
```

My problem is that it isn't nicely formatted, like so:

```
<file/>
<file/>
<file/>
```

Is there any way to add whitespaces in between the elements after CreateElement and AppendChild? I've checked out Doc->put_preserveWhiteSpace, but that does just seem to set whether or not you keep whitespaces from the original XML document.

Comment: For me following solution has worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36408049#36408781

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried simply appending a "text" node with a new line after each `<file/>`?